# Application of 'apply' functions in R

Tags: r, sapply

I have got the following list which was generated by using split function with state as index.

```
 $AK
                   Hospital_Name         State     Mortality_Rate
  99  PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER    AK           13.4
 100   MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    AK           17.7
 102      FAIRBANKS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AK           15.5

 $AL
                                 Hospital_Name        State   Mortality_Rate
  1                 SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER    AL           14.3
  2                    MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH    AL           18.5
  3                   ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL           18.1


$AR
                             Hospital_Name       State   Mortality_Rate
 193           SILOAM SPRINGS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AR           15.6
 194            JOHNSON REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    AR           16.9
 195 WASHINGTON REGIONAL MED CTR AT NORTH HILLS    AR           15.2
```

I want to select Hospital Name of 2nd row from each of these states. Can somebody help with an apply function here? I was trying to use sapply the following way(not working) -

```
       x <- sapply(test.case3,function(i) test.case3[[i]][2,1])
```

so that, by varying 'i', I can get result as follows -

```
   > test.case3[[1]][2,1]
    [1] "MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER"
   > test.case3[[2]][2,1]
    [1] "MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH"
   > test.case3[[3]][2,1]
    [1] "JOHNSON REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER"
```

Kindly advise.

I required to produce the final report in the following format.(ignore the data, in below example)

```
       Hospital_Name                    State
    D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL       AL
   ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER     AR
   JOHN C LINCOLN DEER VALLEY HOSPITAL   AZ
```

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of the data before you split it?

Comment: I don't have the data but try `sapply(test.case3, function(df) df$Hospital_Name[2])`

Comment: @TrevorAlexander
<pre>

                    Hospital_Name State Mortality_Rate
1 SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER    AL           14.3
2    MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH    AL           18.5
3   ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL           18.1 <code>

Comment: @dickoa

                              AK 
"MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER"


I don't want the state names that are appearing in the output if possible

Comment: name are just attribute they don't affect computation but if you insist then do `unname(sapply(test.case3, function(df) df$Hospital_Name[2]))`